# SharePoint working with lookup dropdowns and getting values

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, lookup, dropdown

I seem to have a little trouble getting a value to be returned from a dropdown lookup field.  I've got the following code that gets me the values from the list I'm doing the lookup upon:

```
var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;

function getDropdownValues(tempNumTitle) {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var tempDropdownValueList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Temps');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View>' +
                              '<RowLimit>' +
                                  '100' +
                              '</RowLimit>' +
                          '</View>');

    this.tempQuery = tempDropdownValueList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(tempQuery);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        // on success of getting Temp Values from dropdown
        // match it with the tempNum entry
        function (sender, args) {
            var tempDropDownValues = {};

            var tempEnumerator = tempQuery.getEnumerator();

            while(tempEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var tempItem = tempEnumerator.get_current();
                var tempTitle = tempItem.get_item('Title');
                var tempId = tempItem.get_item('ID');
                tempDropDownValues[tempTitle] = tempId;

            }

            selectTemp(tempNumTitle, tempDropdownValues)
        },
        // on failure
        function (sender, args) {
            console.info('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
    );
}
```

It performs this fine, giving me the dropdown values.  It then calls the function selectTemp with the parameters of the tempNumTitle we are looking for, and the list of dropdown values retrieved.  Here is the next function:

```
function selectTemp(tempNumTitle, tempValues) {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var tempMatchValueList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Numbers-Temp');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View>' +
                              '<Query>' +
                                  '<Where>' +
                                      '<Eq>' +
                                          '<FieldRef Name="Title" />' +
                                          '<Value Type="Text">' + tempNumTitle + '</Value>' +
                                      '</Eq>' +
                                  '</Where>' +
                              '</Query>' +
                          '</View>');

    this.tempMatchValueQuery = tempMatchValueList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(tempMatchValueQuery);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        // on success
        function (sender, args) {
            var temp = '';

            tempEnumerator = tempMatchValueQuery.getEnumerator();
            while(tempEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var tempItem = tempEnumerator.get_current();
                temp = tempItem.get_item('Temp0');
            }
        },
        // on failure
        function (sender, args) {
            console.info('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
    );
}
```

It almost gets me what I'm looking for, but I get something like this:
    temp: {$1E_1: 3, $2e_1: "Temp 3"}

Where I want the value of the $2e_1, or "Temp 3".  How can I get that value, without just going temp["$2e_1"]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When accessing a lookup column or a people picker column, the column value is a complex type rather than a simple string.

You can invoke `.get_lookupValue()` on the returned object to get a text representation of the lookup column's value, or `.get_lookupId()` to get the ID number of the corresponding item in the lookup list (or in the site collection's user information list in the case of a people picker column).

So in your case, assuming "Temp0" is the internal name of a lookup column, you should be able to do this:

```
temp = tempItem.get_item('Temp0').get_lookupValue();
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  That does it.  I just didn't know about the .get_lookup__(); routine, or didn't look hard enough.  You are great!